# Trouble with csv reading and writing

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, bots

I'm new to python and I need some help with the following. I've made a bot for a twitch channel and I'm trying to make it store quotes, then repeat them at random when given a command.

```
import csv
import pickle
oneline= []

def saveFile():
    with open("quotes.csv",'w+') as resultFile:
        wr = csv.writer(resultFile)
        wr.writerow(oneline)


def loadoneline():
    with open("quotes.csv",'r') as resultFile:
        r = csv.reader(resultFile)
        global oneline
        oneline = list(r)
loadoneline()

print(oneline)
```

This is what I have so far which works great until the bot is shut down or restarted. After which it just prints this instead.

```
['["[\'memes\']", \'[]\', \'memes\']', '[]', 'quote', 'this quote', 'and this quote', 'and another quote']
```

All the quotes collected in the current session are fine, but anything that was collected in the previous session gets printed in a single ugly list.

Any insight would be lovely! using python 3.x

Comment: Could you clarify what "fine" is, as well as what's wrong with this? You have it set to print.

Comment: May I see `print(online)` inside `def saveFile():`.

Comment: @AryaMcCarthy the bot gathers quotes from a chat with a !quote command and reads them back at random with a !sass command. If the file was empty, this process works perfectly. But once the bot has been restarted ans has to call the    ```loadonline()``` function, the bot responds like this: 
```TeamTrigg: !sass
DeirdreBot: ['memes', 'more memes']```